# Using the useContext Hook to create a simple To-Do List app in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Can someone tell me if there is anything wrong with the way I have used the Context API in this code. And if there is something wrong can you explain why?

These two are my Contexts

```
import React from "react";

export const ItemListContext = React.createContext();
```

```
import React from "react";

export const ItemContext = React.createContext();
```

This is my App component

```
import "./styles.css";
import TodoList from "./Components/TodoList";
import { ItemContext } from "./Context/ItemContext";
import { ItemListContext } from "./Context/ItemListContext";

import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [inputs, setInput] = useState("");
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ItemContext.Provider value={[inputs, setInput]}>
        <ItemListContext.Provider value={[itemList, setItemList]}>
          <TodoList />
        </ItemListContext.Provider>
      </ItemContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After this I have a Todo List component that looks like this :-

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { ItemContext } from "../Context/ItemContext";
import { ItemListContext } from "../Context/ItemListContext";

const TodoList = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useContext(ItemContext);
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useContext(ItemListContext);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const hanleCLick = () => {
    setItemList((prevList) => [...prevList, input]);
  };
  const handleDelete = (i) => {
    let newList = itemList.filter((item, index) => index !== i);
    setItemList(newList);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={input} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={hanleCLick}>Add Item</button>

      {itemList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>{item}</p>
            <button onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: It looks okay. Did you face any problems with it?

Comment: No. It works perfectly fine. I wrote this in a interview assignment and the guy said that this is not how you use useContext. Did not make any sense to me so wanted to ask the community. So thanks for verifying.

Comment: Usually, we create a separate provider component to create a context, and we declare/initialize all the states and functions in this separate component and provide these using the newly created provider component. If all the states and functions are created in app component then it will messy. you can flow this repo https://github.com/Arifur-Rahaman/todo/blob/main/src/context/todoContext.js Please let me know if you don't understand anything.